# Multiple Follow ID's causing Status 401 error for Twitter stream API

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, twitter-oauth, discord

I am only receiving an error when I add multiple twitter USERid's. When I just one at at time, it's fine, no errors.

Here is my code: https://hastebin.com/bitabojuhe.js

When I add more than one, it returns this error. The keys are fine because as soon as I delete the array and just make one user ID it works again. Very strange issue.

Error: Status Code: 401

```
at Request.emit
at ClientRequest.emit 
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete
at TLSSocket.socketOnData 
at TLSSocket.emit 
at addChunk 
at readableAddChunk
```

Comment: The error is self explanatory, 401 - Unauthorized, maybe you don't have access to do that. Wrap your function in a promise and use Promise.all to get all your id's.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Any idea on how to do that? I'm still a bit new to all this. I have provided a link above.